# Using plus symbol in SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, special-characters

I want to use the plus symbol, +, is a SQL CASE statement. For example:

```
CASE
    WHEN t=1 THEN 1+
END AS example
```

I've tried using escape characters with no success. How do I do this?

Comment: Explain what you're trying to achieve. Your definitely not on the right track...

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*. It computes a *value*. It doesn't produce "extra content that SQL will parse and insert into a larger expression" which it seems is what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: @jarlh When the case statement is true (ie t equals 1) I want the output to be "1+".

Comment: I figured out my issue. I had several WHEN conditions within my CASE statement. Some were integer outputs and I wanted a string output. When all the outputs are strings then I get the output as '11+'.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you just need to treat it as a string

```
CASE
    WHEN t=1 THEN '1+'
END AS example
```

Or if you want to add 1 to the number, there is no such thing (like `Param++` in #C and java) , in that case:

```
CASE
    WHEN t=1 THEN t+1
END AS example
```

Comment: Strangely your first code example doesn't work for me. I do want the output to be '1+' but I get an error when I run your example.

Comment: @DimJim - when you get "an error", please specify *what* error. And maybe show more of your sql statement and/or how you want to use that "1+".

Comment: @DimJim , as Hans said, you need to provide the full error , and the entire code you are using(perhaps the error comes from somewhere else).